# Error says that the program is missing a return statement. Help find the error in the program I've already written

Tags: java, return

I am having trouble understanding what is wrong here. I have to do this project for my class and already found the answer so thank you guys 
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("You must choose a number from 1 to 4. Try again!");
                menu();
                choice = input.nextInt();
            }

```
    }

    public static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
        // If running on Java 6 or older, use `new Random()` on RHS here
        Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            int a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
    }

    public static void menu() {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Select one of the following options");
        System.out.println("1. Question 1");

        System.out.println("2. Question 2");

        System.out.println("3. Question 3");

        System.out.println("4. Question 4");

        System.out.println("5. Question 5");

        System.out.println("6. Question 6");

        System.out.println("7. Question 7");

        System.out.println("8. Question 8");

        System.out.println("9. Question 9");

        System.out.println("10. Question 10");

        System.out.println("11. Turn in Test");
        System.out.println("12. Exit");
    }

    public static void Quit() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static char Question(String reference) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(reference);
        System.out.println("Please enter answer in caps");
        char answer = input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(answer);


    }

    public static int gradeTest(char key, char userAnswers) {
        int points;

        if (key == userAnswers) {
            points = 1;
        } else {
            points = 0;
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error already say's what is it? Try to understand it.  Hints: Looks at `public static char Question(String reference)` method.

Comment: A simple [MCVE] would have solved this.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static char Question(String reference)
```

needs to return a char.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char Question(String reference) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(reference);
    System.out.println("Please enter answer in caps");
    char answer = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(answer);
```

You need to return the char on that method